# Numerical tests of Titius–Bode formula for artificial planetary orbits

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, planets, solar-system

[Titius–Bode law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law) is an empirical formula stating that positions of planets in Solar system is described by:

$$a=0.4+0.3 \times 2^m [AU],$$
where $m$ are natural numbers.

All planets, with exception of Neptune, fall within a few percent of it. Moreover, it predicted the existence of Uranus (so, at least to me, it does not sound like a coincidence).

There are simulators of solar system formation ([even some online](http://www.nowykurier.com/toys/gravity/gravity.html)).

Are there numerical simulations generating such orbits (as expected from Titius–Bode law). Or are they showing that there is no preference for such orbits?

See also:

- [Why do the planets' orbital distances fall on an exponential curve?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18793/why-do-the-planets-orbital-distances-fall-on-an-exponential-curve)

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the Wikipedia article you linked that this law is really *not a law*, but just a lucky guess. Therefore, one does not expect these proposed orbits to 'naturally' appear in numerical simulations, and I doubt you could find anything to that effect.

Comment: @Danu I understand that it is not a (universal) _law_, but a formula (though I use _law_ as in a proper name). Since it 1) has much less parameters than the number of orbits and 2) it was used to _predict_ (so not only fitting) I am not persuaded that is a "lucky guess" (unless I am given some statistical measure how lucky it is). And in particular a numerical results saying that orbits do not follow this formula would persuade me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do the planets' orbital distances fall on an exponential curve?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18793/)

Comment: @BenCrowell Seriously? (Especially as I am aware of this question.)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: As far as I can tell, this question is a subset of that one.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal - while "see also" with link indicates that you are aware of the other question you might want to elaborate (in the body of the question) what makes this one different (and that answer not applicable)

Comment: Does the other question ask, or refer to, any numerical simulations? "Because there is other question referring to an exponential fit to planet positions" is not a thing that makes sense.