# Orbital distances of planets

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, geometry, solar-system

So is the [exponential pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law) in the planetary distances related to Johann Kepler's discovery in 1596 that the ratios of the orbits of the six planets known in his day were the same as the ratios between nested Platonic solids who called it the Mysterium Cosmographicum?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18793/2451

Answer (score 0):

No. In fact, it was Kepler who discovered it when he failed to make his model fit. The best explanation for the orbits was that they were ellipses.

So why is the semi-major axes of the planets like they are? They form a sequence that is fairly close to $0.4+0.3\times 2^n$ (the [Titius-Bode law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law)) except that it fails for Neptune.

It is generally believed today that the distances are essentially random results of the initial distribution of matter in the solar nebula -- the "law" above is just chance. Due to the declining density of the protoplanetary disk as one moves outwards distances between planets get larger, and even random locations will tend to fit *some* numerical pattern.